# SQL Server: Filter for only the rows directly after a row containing specific text

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas, indexing, filter

I have a table with the following columns

```
application_uuid
changed_at_utc
changed_by 
name
```

I would like to sort by `application_uuid` and `changed_at_utc`. Then, I want to filter for only the rows that come directly after rows where `application_status` has the text 'Ready for Scoring'

With Python and Pandas, I would do something like this...

```
application_statuses = application_statuses.sort_values(['application_uuid', 'changed_at_utc'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
indexes = application_statuses[application_statuses['application_status']=='Ready for Scoring'].index + 1
next_statuses = application_statuses.ix[indexes]
```

How can I do the same thing using SQL?

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your explanation, you can use the `lead` function to do this.

```
select next_application_status,application_uuid,changed_at_utc,changed_by
from (select t.*,
      lead(application_status) over(order by application_uuid,changed_at_utc) as next_appliaction_status
      from tablename t
      ) t1
where application_status = 'Ready for Scoring'
```

If this has to be done for each `application_uuid` , include a `partition by` in `lead` like below.

```
select next_application_status,application_uuid,changed_at_utc,changed_by
from (select t.*,
      lead(application_status) over(partition by application_uuid order by changed_at_utc) as next_appliaction_status
      from tablename t
      ) t1
where application_status = 'Ready for Scoring'
```

If you need *all* the rows after application_status `Ready for Scoring`, get the timestamp of that specific row and choose all the other timestamps which are greater. This assumes an application_uuid will have at most one row with `Ready for Scoring` status.

```
select application_status,application_uuid,changed_at_utc,changed_by
from (select t.*,
      max(case when application_status='Ready for Scoring' then changed_at_utc end) over(partition by application_uuid) as status_time
      from tablename t
      ) t1
where changed_at_utc > status_time
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for